# Is there a Python equivalent of Java's IdentityHashMap?

Tags: java, python, object-identity

I'm walking a data structure and would like to build a dict mapping X->Y, where X is a field in the data structure I'm walking and Y is a field in the data structure I'm building on the fly.  X is an unhashable type.

Comment: If X is unhashable then it stand to reason that it can change (Making Mapping a bit hard). Do you want to it be that that 'X' instance always points to that 'Y' instance? Or do you want any X of that value to point to that 'Y'. If it's the first one then you can assign a id to each X and the id should then be mapped to a 'Y'. If it's the second one then you can store X in a hashable container temporarily such as a tuple and use that as a key. I'm sure there are probably faster ways to do this (My pythons a bit rusty), but it should work.

Comment: @Xonar: Pretty sure you can't hash a tuple containing unhashable items

Comment: Yes, true. (I did say my python is rusty :)) but you can recursuvely add the unhashable items into tuple. e.g. Turn (1,2,[2,3]) into (1,2,(2,3)) Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivially:

```
idmap = {}
idmap[id(x)] = y
```

Use the `id` of `x` as the dictionary key

Comment: Note that for custom classes, `hash(x)` defaults to `id(x)` - you'll find `id` is unnecessary here in some cases.

Comment: Note that `x` must survive via a reference elsewhere to guarantee that its `id` won’t be reused.

Comment: Downvoted because as @DavisHerring said it is subtly broken, possibly leading to random errors since the id can be reused

Answer (score 2):

Often, the broken solution given to this common problem is to use `id`.
It is broken because `id` is only unique among existing objects, so the following can randomly happen:

```
>>> idmap = {}
>>> idmap[id(x)] = 42
>>> del x
>>> z = SomeObject()
>>> z in idmap
True
```

No explicit `del` statement has to happen, just adding a key to idmap inside a function could lead to the same result:

```
>>> def add_smthg(idmap):
>>>     x = SomeObject()
>>>     idmap[id(x)] = 42

>>> idmap = {}
>>> add_smthg(idmap)
>>> z = SomeObject()
>>> z in idmap
True
```

To avoid this, you have to keep a reference of each object you insert. IMHO the only viable option is to create new dictionnary / set classes:

```
class IdentitySet:
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        if items is None:
            items = []

        self._identities = {id(item): item for item in items}

    def add(self, item):
        self._identities[id(item)] = item
    
    def __delitem__(self, item):
        del self._identities[id(item)]

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return id(item) in self._identities


class IdentityDict:
    def __init__(self, pairs=None):
        if pairs is None:
            pairs = []

        self._identities = IdentitySet(k for k, _ in pairs)
        self._values = {id(k): v for k, v in pairs}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._values[id(item)]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self._identities.add(item)
        self._values[id(item)] = value
    
    def __delitem__(self, item):        
        del self._identities[item]
        del self._values[id(item)]
    
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._identities
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Java's IdentityHashMap is to simulate dynamic field. Since Python language already supports dynamic attributes directly, you don't need the map, just assign Y to an X's attribute

```
x.someSuchRelation = y;
```

Comment: Not all objects in Python support dynamic attributes!

Comment: This requires you to choose a unique name for the field

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular Python `dict` for this if you wrap your unhashable objects in another object. Specifically, something like this:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, o):
        self.o = o

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.o)

    def __eq__(self, o):
        return hash(self) == hash(o)
```

Then just use it like `some_dict[Wrapper(unhashable_object)]`.

This is a more useful approach than just using `id(o)` as the key if you also need to be able to access the object itself afterwards (as `key.o`, obviously). If you don't (and garbage collection isn't an issue), just use that.

Comment: You should not implement equality in terms of hash equality - the size of py_hash_t may be smaller than the size of a pointer.