# Checking for duplicate arrays when I have a huge amount of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, hash

I am counting various patterns in graphs, and I store the relevant information in a defaultdict of lists of numpy arrays of size N, where the index values are integers.

I want to efficiently know if I am creating a duplicate array.  Not removing duplicates can exponentially grow the amount of duplicates to the point where what I am doing becomes infeasible.  But there are potentially hundreds of thousands of arrays, stored in different lists, under different keys.  As far as I know, I can't hash an array.

If I simply needed to check for duplicate nonzero indices, I would store the nonzero indices as a bit sequence of ones and then hash that value.  But, I don't only need to check the indices - I need to also check their integer values.  Is there any way to do this short of coming up with a completely knew design that uses different structures?

Thanks.

Comment: If your arrays are the same size why don'y you use a matrix and remove the duplicates by using `np.unique(array, axis=0)`?

Comment: I don't know how many arrays I will have at any given iteration, and I think appending numpy arrays is expensive(someone can correct me if I am wrong please).  I could do this and it will *partially* solve the problem, but I am not sure how much benefit it would be.

Comment: Well if you're generating arrays through iteration if each iteration is supposed to take a considerable time then your best bet would be using tuples which are immutable and hashable plus a set to keep the unique arrays. Otherwise just use a numpy array (You can create that array using `np.fromiter` function) and remove the duplicates using `np.unique(arr, axis=0)`. Also don't forget that you always can run benchmarks to see if the cost of converting your iterable into a numpy array and performing `np.unique` will overcome the cost of removing the duplicates.

Comment: "I can't hash an array": `ndarray`s do not work with the built-in `hash` function (to prevent them from being used as `dict` keys, which is another story) however the underlying data absolutely can be hashed, for example with `hash(x.tobytes())`. Would that help to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is “How can I use my own `hash` (and perhaps `==`) to store things differently in a `set`/`dict`?” (where “differently” includes “without raising `TypeError` for being non-hashable).

The **first part** of the answer is defining your hash function, for example following [myrtlecat’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672229/checking-for-duplicate-arrays-when-i-have-a-huge-amount-of-arrays#comment92276564_52672229).  However, beware the standard **non-answer** based on it: store the custom hash of each object in a `set` (or map it to, say, the original object with a `dict`).  That you don’t have to provide an equality implementation is a hint that this is wrong: hash values aren’t *always* unique!  (Exception: if you want to [“hash by identity”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17054084/8586227), and know all your keys will **outlive** the map, `id` *does* provide unique “hashes”.)

The **rest** of the answer is to wrap your desired keys in objects that expose your hash/equality functions as `__hash__` and `__eq__`.  Note that overriding the non-hashability of mutable types comes with an obligation to **not alter** the (underlying) keys!  (C programmers would often call doing so *undefined behavior*.)

For code, see an [old answer by xperroni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5173201/8586227) (which includes the option to increase safety by basing the comparisons on private copies that are less likely to be altered by some other code), though I’d add `__slots__` to combat the memory overhead.